# I have table in SQL Server as shown - how to get the desired output?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table

```
Date1      | Date2       | Days
-------------------------------
2017-01-25   2017-02-03     8
```

How to turn this into an output like this:

```
Periode | Days
--------------
January    5
February   3
```

Comment: you table data looks incomplete

Comment: Like a count of weekdays?

Comment: weekdays still count

Comment: example :
2017-01-25 until 2017-01-31 = 5 days ( this includes January periode )
and the rest 
2017-02-01 untill 2017-02-03 = 3 days ( this includes Februari periode )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could generate a count of the weekdays in a given period, based on two column's values, using a `CROSS APPLY` to generate the dates that aren't weekdays, then grouping by the `DATENAME` of the month of each of those dates.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Date1 DATE, Date2 DATE); -- Days field doesn't matter. 
INSERT @TABLE(Date1, Date2) VALUES
    ('2017-01-25', '2017-02-03'); 

WITH CTE1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) A(B)),
     CTE2(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM CTE1 A CROSS JOIN CTE1 B CROSS JOIN CTE1) -- Generate numbers 0-999. 

SELECT Periode = DATENAME(MONTH, D.Dates),
       Days = COUNT(*)
FROM @TABLE T
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT Dates = DATEADD(DAY, C.N, T.Date1) 
    FROM CTE2 C
    WHERE C.N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, T.Date1, T.Date2) -- Generate all dates between Date1 and Date2.
    AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, C.N, T.Date1)) NOT IN (1, 7) -- Where the day isn't Saturday/Sunday. 
) D
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, D.Dates), DATEPART(MONTH, D.Dates)
ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, D.Dates)
;
```

**EDIT:**

As per comments about the actual needs here, this is how you'd work out the actual amount of days within a month, based on `DATETIME` columns:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Date1 DATETIME, Date2 DATETIME); -- Days field doesn't matter. 
INSERT @TABLE(Date1, Date2) VALUES
    ('2017-01-25 15:00:00.000', '2017-02-03 03:00:00.000'); 

WITH CTE1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) A(B)),
     CTE2(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM CTE1 A CROSS JOIN CTE1 B CROSS JOIN CTE1) -- Generate numbers 0-999. 

SELECT Periode = DATENAME(MONTH, D.Date1),
       Days = SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, D.Date1, D.Date2)) / 24.0 -- Total hours in month / 24.0 for the number of days. 
FROM @TABLE T
CROSS APPLY -- Calculate the start and end of each day within a the period. 
(
    SELECT Date1 = CASE C.N WHEN 0 THEN T.Date1 ELSE DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, C.N, T.Date1)), 0) END, -- Start of each day.
           Date2 = CASE WHEN C.N = DATEDIFF(DAY, T.Date1, T.Date2) THEN T.Date2 ELSE DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, C.N, T.Date1)), 1) END -- End of each day. 
    FROM CTE2 C
    WHERE C.N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, T.Date1, T.Date2)
) D
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, D.Date1), DATEPART(MONTH, D.Date1)
ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, D.Date1)
;
```

Given the sample data, this produces 6.375 days in January (6 full days plus 9 hours from the 25th) and 2.125 days in February (2 full days plus 3 hours on the 3rd) for a total of 8.5 days.

Comment: ok it's work 
but how if  
date1 = 2017-01-25
date2 = 2017-02-03
days = 8.5

it's should be
January = 5
februari = 3.5 
can you fix it?

Comment: @MahfudFoed Why would it be 8.5, and why would you add the 0.5 onto the 3 instead of the 5?

Comment: so the query will be like what ?
i'm sory too many questions
it's so difficult for me

Comment: this the formula to get date range
select DATEADD(HOUR,(8.5*24),'2017-01-25 15:00')

Comment: Why is it 8.5? How does the 0.5 get added?

Comment: because 8.5 calculated based on hour, so that if we input 8.5 datetime range  will be show automaticaly   2017-02-03 03:00 
example :  
select DATEADD(HOUR,(8.5*24),'2017-01-25 15:00')
output :  2017-02-03 03:00

Comment: Are your date columns `DATETIME`? Where does the time come from? I'll add a modified example of how you'd work out the total split, I guess, based on them being datetimes.

Comment: yes my date columns is datetime
and time it was set manually and it was 15:00

Comment: i wanna Ask
how to make button back, when clicked the previous data not lose in javascript Or php